# Is it possible to push back values in a vector in a map? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, vector, unordered-map

So let's say I declare a map of **keys my_type** (where "my_type" is a class that can be multiple different types allowing the vector to be heterogeneous - let's just assume this works for the sake of differentiating the vectors) **mapping to a vector of pointers to vectors of my_type**, like so:

```
unordered_map<my_type, vector<vector<my_type>*>> my_map;
```

And I have the following vectors:

```
vector<my_type> vec1 = {"Adam", 1}
vector<my_type> vec2 = {"Kevin", 2}
vector<my_type> vec3 = {"Kevin", 3}
vector<my_type> vec4 = {"Kevin", 4}
vector<my_type> vec5 = {"Richard", 5}
vector<my_type> vec6 = {"Sam", 6}
```

Now let's say I want to add in each of these vectors as values to the unordered_map, with the string names at index 0 as the key for each. My aim is to be able to store multiple vectors that may have the same key in the unordered_map, (much in the same way as a multimap works, except without using multimap).

I want to make it such that a pointer to each vector (vec1, vec2, ... vec6) gets pushed back in the vector in the map that corresponds to the given key. If a key points to a vector which already contains a pointer to a value, I want to push a pointer to the new value to the back of that vector so now it can have two, with both essentially sharing the same key. Then, I hope to access duplicate values of the same key all in one map by indexing through vector.

**So essentially, the key "Kevin" would point to a vector of pointers, where the pointer at index 0 -> vec2, the pointer at index 1 -> vec3, and the pointer at index 2 -> vec4.**

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how? Some example syntax would be appreciated. Also I am aware this can be accomplished with a multimap but I am trying to do this without one for several reasons so I just ask that you do not suggest one. Thanks, and I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: There is no problem except the complexity that one inadvertently introduces in various ways. E.g. I would not use a pointer to a vector, just a vector.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Okay, that is a good point. Could you explain how exactly I can access the vector in a map and push back a value? That is what I am confused about.

Comment: Given a map `m` of type `map<Key, vector<Value>>`, e.g. `m[key].push_back( value )`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make it such that a pointer to each vector (vec1, vec2, ... vec6) gets pushed back in the vector in the map that corresponds to the given key.

```
my_map["Adam"].push_back(&vec1);
my_map["Kevin"].push_back(&vec2);
my_map["Kevin"].push_back(&vec3);
my_map["Kevin"].push_back(&vec4);
...etc...
```

That said, Alf's right - 't usually be better to avoid pointers and have `my_map` be a proper, independent variable owning its own data and deallocating it if `my_map` goes out of scope, is `new`-ed then `delete`-d etc..